# Is it possible to change primary field of custom entity after it has been created in dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-365

I have many custom entities for that I need to change primary field, I already know creating workflow that will update values of primary field by coping it from different field. But I don't want to do that.

Is there any way to change primary field of custom entity after it has been created?

Answer (score 4):

The primary field of an Entity (as well other custom fields) cannot be changed after the creation. If you must change the primary field name, you need to delete and recreate the Entity.

Answer (score 0):

You said change, what kind of change you need. Pick your answer from below.

**On Create of new entity: changes in primary field (new_name)**

Display name change - possible.
Data type change - impossible.
Schema name change - possible.
Requirement level change - possible.

**On Update of entity: changes in primary field (new_lookupdisplaytext)**

Display name change - possible.
Data type change - impossible.
Schema name change - impossible.
Requirement level change - impossible.

Comment: On Update of entity I want to do requirement level change, Basically I want to replace primary field with different field.

Comment: So you got the answer, it's not allowed. Either drop & recreate entity, or use WF to cascade the data stored in different field to existing primary field.

Comment: Or try business rules.